# Strange memory leak inside loop

Tags: c++

I have memory leak problem in my working project. Actually, I have read some of the references about memory leak and found that every `new` should be `delete` then, but unfortunately, I can't delete the pointer when the loop is not over yet. I need the advice to deal with this problem then.

Main program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "linspace.h"
#include "matrik.h"
#include "vektor.h"
#include "FV.h"

using namespace std;
matrik WENO5CPLFRK3(matrik w, double aumax, double dx, double dt, int Ne, int Nt);

int main()
{
    double CFL, tm, t;
    CFL = 0.5;
    tm = 1;
    t = .0;


    int Ne, Np;
    Ne = 1000;
    Np = Ne + 1;

    int Ng, Nt;
    Ng = 3;
    Nt = Ne + Ng + Ng;

    double lb, rb, dx;
    vektor x(Np);
    matrik w(3, Ne);
    matrik q(3, Ne), qn(3, Ne), qm(3, Ne);
    matrik dF(3, Ne);
    double aumax, dt;
    lb = 0.;
    rb = 1.;
    dx = (rb - lb)/Ne;

    x = linspace(lb, rb, Np);
    w = initial(x, Ne);
    aumax = soundspeedmax(w, Ne);
    dt = CFL*dx/aumax;

    int iter = 0;

    while (t < tm){
        cout << "Iteration: "<< ++iter << endl;
        w = WENO5CPLFRK3(w,aumax,dx,dt,Ne,Nt);
        t += dt;
        aumax = soundspeedmax(w, Ne);
        dt = CFL*dx/aumax;
//        cout << t<< endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Ne; i++){
        cout <<setprecision(10) << w[0][i] << "," << setprecision(3) << w[1][i] << "," << setprecision(3) << w[2][i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

matrik WENO5CPLFRK3(matrik w, double aumax, double dx, double dt, int Ne, int Nt)
{
    matrik dF(3, Ne), qn(3, Ne), q(3, Ne);

    qn = Q(w, Ne);

    dF = WENO5LFCMP(w, aumax, dx, Ne, Nt);
//
    q = qn - dt*dF;
    w = W(q, Ne);
    dF = WENO5LFCMP(w, aumax, dx, Ne, Nt);

    q = 0.75*qn + 0.25*(q - dt*dF);
    w = W(q, Ne);
    dF = WENO5LFCMP(w, aumax, dx, Ne, Nt);

    q = (qn + 2.*(q - dt*dF))/3.;
    w = W(q, Ne);
    return w;
}
```

I found that `dF` is the cause of memory leak.
This is my `WENO5LFCMP` function:

```
matrik WENO5LFCMP(matrik w, double aumax, double dx, int Ne, int Nt)
{
    int r = 3;
    int Ng = (Nt - Ne)/2;
    matrik wb(3, Nt);
    matrik q(3, Nt);

    wb = boundary(w, Ne, Ng);
    q = Q(wb, Nt);

    double ql[Nt][3], qr[Nt][3];

    for (int i = r - 1; i < Nt - r + 1; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            for (int j = - 2; j < 3; j++){
                v[j + 2] = q[k][i - j];
            }
            vc = WENO5(v);
            ql[i+1][k] = vc[1];
            qr[i][k] = vc[0];
        }
    }
    delete[] vc;

    double** Flux = new double*[Ne + 1];
    for(int j = 0; j < Ne + 1; j++){
        Flux[j] = new double[3];
    }

    for (int i = r; i < Nt-r+1; i++){
        Flux[i -r] = LFFlux(ql[i], qr[i], aumax);
    }

    matrik dF(3, Ne);

    for (int i = 0; i < Ne; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            dF[j][i] = (Flux[i + 1][j] - Flux[i][j])/dx;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < Ne + 1; j++){
        delete[] Flux[j];
    } delete[] Flux;

    return dF;

}
```

Edit: `matrik` header:

```
#ifndef MATRIK_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIK_H_INCLUDED

class matrik
{
private:
    int rows, columns;
    double** src;

public:
    matrik();
    matrik(int ROWS, int COLS);
    matrik(const matrik&);
    ~matrik();

double* operator[](int i) const { return src[i]; }
double& operator()(int i, int j) { return src[i][j]; }

matrik& operator=(const matrik&);
matrik& operator+=(const matrik&);
matrik& operator-=(const matrik&);

friend matrik operator+(const matrik&, const matrik&);
friend matrik operator-(const matrik&, const matrik&);
friend matrik operator*(double, const matrik&);
friend matrik operator*(const matrik&, double);
friend matrik operator/(double, const matrik&);
friend matrik operator/(const matrik&, double);

};

#endif // OVERLOADING_H_INCLUDED
```

Implemetation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrik.h"

using namespace std;

matrik::matrik()
{
    src = 0;
    columns = rows = 0;
}

matrik::matrik(int m, int n)
{
    rows = m;
    columns = n;

    src = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        src[i] = new double[columns];
    }
}

matrik::matrik(const matrik& M)
{
    rows = M.rows;
    columns = M.columns;

    src = new double*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        src[i] =  new double[columns];
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) src[i][j] = M[i][j];
    }
}

inline matrik::~matrik()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) delete[] src[i];
    delete[] src;
}

matrik& matrik::operator=(const matrik& M)
{
    if (this != &M){
        if (rows != M.rows || columns != M.columns){
            //
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                src[i][j] = M[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Simplest solution: Use standard library containers, such as `std::vector` and `std::array` (and never write `new` again)

Comment: Looks like the problem is in 
            vc = WENO5(v);
            ql[i+1][k] = vc[1];
            qr[i][k] = vc[0];

Can't you add a delete vc there, inside the loop? Otherwise, the solution would be to redesign the return type of WENO5.

Comment: Since `dF` is a `matrik` you should look for the problem there.

Comment: When you already have a `matrik` class why not use that instead of a raw jagged array.

Comment: check the `operator=`, copy ctor  and dtor of `matrik` class. looks like the problem is there. if one of them doesn't exists it may also be the problem. you also should have move ctor and operator.

Comment: hmm I will try to use `std::array` instead of customized one @UnholySheep

Comment: The delete[] should really be in a destructor as part of a class so you don’t have to call it over and over again. You’re making you’re life a lot harder than it needs to be. Upvote for std::vector.

Comment: `double ql[Nt][3], qr[Nt][3];` is VLA extension, and so not valid C++.

Comment: @indra This is not a [mcve].  You did not post `matrik`, and you are returning this type by value and passing it to functions by value.  If a type is returned or passed by value, it needs to have proper copy semantics, i.e. behaves "properly" when copied (no memory leaks, no memory corruption, makes actual copies and not bogus ones, etc.).  We have no idea if `matrik` has proper copy semantics, thus your question is incomplete.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have add `matrik` in the post

Comment: And `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @indra  The assignment operator is incomplete and faulty.  Why is it checking to see if the passed in matrix has the same dimensions as `this`?  It should not matter what the dimensions are of the passed in parameter.  The assignment operator has one job to do, and that should be removing the old data and creating a duplicate of the data that is passed in.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah likely to check that the dimension of lhs matrix are equal to rhs matrix, so each element of rhs matrix is transferred to the lhs matrix. I don't know if it's not needed?

Comment: @indra -- There is no need to check the matrix sizes.   The assignment operator's purpose is to take what is passed-in, throw away what is currently in `this`, and assign the contents.  If someone says `a = b;`, this means that you should be taking `b`, throwing away whatever `a` had before, and just create `a` that will have the same contents of `b`.  You are not doing that now -- you are creating fake copies of the right-hand-side.  In addition you are creating a memory leak and potentially writing beyond the bounds of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is very far away from idiomatic C++. In idiomatic C++ `new` and `delete` are not used in such code as yours. Instead of `new[]` and `delete[]` you should use `std::vector`, which will eliminate memory leaks. Instead of  `new T` and `delete` you should use `std::make_unique<T>()`.

Having said that, even if you keep your `new` and `delete`, the code has several problems. For example, look at the loop:

```
for (int i = r - 1; i < Nt - r + 1; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        for (int j = - 2; j < 3; j++){
            v[j + 2] = q[k][i - j];
        }
        vc = WENO5(v);  // <--- allocation
        ql[i+1][k] = vc[1];
        qr[i][k] = vc[0];
    }
}
delete[] vc;
```

The `delete[] vc`, at the end, indicates that memory is allocated at an earlier assignment:

```
        vc = WENO5(v);
```

But since the allocation is in the loop, then `delete[] vc` should also be in the loop. Otherwise future iterations will lose the previous value of `vc` which will leak memory.

I hope that the missing pieces of code in `matrik::operator=` is re-allocating memory if sizes don't match, and it does that without leaking.

---

I can't stress enough - if you can avoid it, don't use dynamic memory allocation. Leave that to the pros who wrote `std::vector` and at least `std::make_unique()`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, right now I am rewriting using `std::vector`. I feel this is more effective and efficient considering my code type (numeric for scientific computing).